# Show that matrix is unitary

Tags: unitary-matrices

Suppose $0\neq v \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Show that the matrix
$$U=I - 2\frac{vv^H}{\|v\|^2}$$
is unitary (with $^H$ being the conjugate transpose and I the identity matrix).

What I've tried:

A matrix U is unitary if $U^HU$ is equal to the identity matrix. So I've tried to plug U into this term but unfortunately I really don't know how to calculate the conjugate transpose of this long string.
Another tip: The script hints to Schur decomposition, which may be useful, but I don't know how I could apply it to this problem.

Comment: Hello, I think $U$ is not unitary as you have defined it. However if you define $U = I - 2\frac{vv^H}{||v||^2}$ then you can show it is unitary "by hand".

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to add the ^2. Could you give me a hint on how to show this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \frac{vv^H}{\|v\|^2}$, I interpret this as the matrix with coefficients $A_{ij} = v_i \overline{v_j}$.

Then $(A^H)_{ij} = \overline{A_{ji}} = \overline{v_j \overline{v_i}}= \overline{v_j} v_i = A_{ij}$, so $A^H = A$.

Similarly we can show $A^HA = A^H = A$, the result then follows from a direct calculation of $U^HU$.

Answer (score 1):

No decomposition necessary. The straight-forward calculation workds:

\begin{align}
U^HU
&= \left(I-2\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2}\right)^H \left(I-2\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2}\right) \\
&= \left(I^H-2\frac{\left(vv^H\right)^H}{|v|^2}\right) \left(I-2\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2}\right) \\
&= \left(I-2\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2}\right) \left(I-2\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2}\right) \\
&= \left(I -4\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2} + 4\frac{(vv^H) (vv^H)}{|v|^4}\right) \\
&= \left(I -4\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2} + 4\frac{v(v^H v)v^H}{|v|^4}\right) \\
&= \left(I -4\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2} + 4\frac{vv^H}{|v|^2}\right) \\
&= I
\end{align}

hope this helps.

In particular we used the formulas:
\begin{align}
(vv^H)^H &= {v^H}^H v^H = vv^H \\
v^Hv &=|v|^2
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!!